# google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 14:9 : Message type "tensorflow.TensorShapeProto" has no field named "unknow_rank"

Tags: tensorflow

When I want to convert my model' format from .pbtxt to .pb, and I got this error:

```
google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 14:9 : Message type "tensorflow.TensorShapeProto" has no field named "unknow_rank".
```

Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pbtxt_to_pb.py", line 15, in <module>
    new_graph_def=text_format.Merge(f.read(), graph_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 702, in Merge
    allow_unknown_field=allow_unknown_field)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 770, in MergeLines
    return parser.MergeLines(lines, message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 795, in MergeLines
    self._ParseOrMerge(lines, message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 817, in _ParseOrMerge
    self._MergeField(tokenizer, message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 942, in _MergeField
    merger(tokenizer, message, field)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 1016, in _MergeMessageField
    self._MergeField(tokenizer, sub_message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 942, in _MergeField
    merger(tokenizer, message, field)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 1016, in _MergeMessageField
    self._MergeField(tokenizer, sub_message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 942, in _MergeField
    merger(tokenizer, message, field)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 1016, in _MergeMessageField
    self._MergeField(tokenizer, sub_message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 942, in _MergeField
    merger(tokenizer, message, field)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 1016, in _MergeMessageField
    self._MergeField(tokenizer, sub_message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 909, in _MergeField
    (message_descriptor.full_name, name))
google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 14:9 : Message type "tensorflow.TensorShapeProto" has no field named "unknow_rank".
```

And here is the code I used to convert it:

```python
import argparse
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.core.framework import graph_pb2
from google.protobuf import text_format

if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('input_pbtxt', help='input pbtxt to be converted')
  parser.add_argument('output_pb', help='output pb generated')
  args = parser.parse_args()
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    with tf.gfile.FastGFile(args.input_pbtxt, 'rb') as f:
      graph_def = graph_pb2.GraphDef()
      new_graph_def = text_format.Merge(f.read(), graph_def)
    tf.train.write_graph(new_graph_def, './', args.output_pb, as_text=False)
```

I don’t know much about [TensorFlow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TensorFlow). How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

When I change the operator from "SquardDifference" to "PowerDifference", I should change something in the model. The first step is to convert ".pb" model to ".pbtxt", and then add one node and change one input from "SquardDifference" to "PowerDifference", but I change all "SquardDifference".

Solution:

Check .pbtxt, and change back where it was wrongly modified.